# how to solve 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type. for typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got error for  const image = new Image(); like this

> 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly
> has an 'any' type.

and

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

How to solve error like that?

```
const onPreview = async (file: UploadFile) => {
    let src = file.url as string;
    if (!src) {
      src = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.originFileObj as RcFile);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
      });
    }
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
    const imgWindow = window.open(src);
    imgWindow?.document.write(image.outerHTML);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your trying to use [`HTMLImageElement: Image() constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) And not a external package.

Try installing [`@types/node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node),

```
npm install --save @types/node
// or
yarn add -D @types/node
```